# Syntax for list construction / concatenation

Tags: list, haskell, syntax

I've only been at Haskell for two days now, and was wondering what the difference between the two function definitions below are:

```
Prelude> let swap (x1:x2:xs) = x2:x1:xs
Prelude> swap [1..5]
[2,1,3,4,5]
Prelude> let swap' (x1:x2:xs) = [x2] ++ [x1] ++ xs
Prelude> swap' [1..5]
[2,1,3,4,5]
```

That is, what makes x2:x1:xs different from [x2] ++ [x1] ++ xs ?
Please and thanks.

Comment: What do you mean different?  Their denotations are the same, i.e., swap and swap' do the same thing.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The type signatures are a good place to start:

```
(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]
(++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
```

You can find these out with `:type (:)` and `:type (++)` in ghci.

As you can see from the type signatures, both are used to produce lists.

The `:` operator is used to construct lists (and to take them apart again for pattern matching).  To make a list `[1,2,3]` you just build it up with `1 : 2 : 3 : []`.  The first element of `:` is the item to add on the front of the list, and the second element is either a list (also built up with `:` or the empty list signified by `[]`).

The `++` operator is list concatenation.  It takes two lists and appends them together.  `[1,2,3] ++ [4,5,6]` is legal, whereas `1 ++ [1,2,3]` is not.

Comment: It's getting clearer. With the top one, I was creating one list from one list, whereas with the bottom one I created 3 and concat'd them all back together. Does that mean the top one would be faster / more efficient?

Comment: In the top one, you are creating the list by the first two elements swapped and the same tail.  In the second one you are creating the list by taking the first two apart, then building them into lists and concatenating them with the tail.  I'd guess that the first one would be more efficient, but I don't think that's the most important thing.  The first one is more idiomatic Haskell in my opinion, so that's why you should choose it.

Comment: Thanks! After the explanations here and more studying today, it's all making more sense.

Answer (score 6):

This has nothing to do with syntax. (:) and (++) are just different operators. (:) is a constructor who constructs a list from an element and another list. (++) makes a new list that is the concatenation of two lists. Because (++) is not a constructor you can't use it in patterns.

Now we come to Syntax: the notation

```
[x2]
```

that you use is a shorthand for

```
x2:[]
```

So what you really have done in the second example is:

```
(x2:[]) ++ (x1:[]) ++ xs
```

Therefore, when constructing a list, you can't avoid (:), it's ultimatively the only way to do it. Note that you must construct intermediate lists to be able to use (++).